# Ehcache low memory behaviour

Tags: java, hibernate, ehcache, out-of-memory

I am using ehcache 1.2.3. Since the cache size is specified in terms of "elements", the
memory which the cache occupies may vary greatly (the ehcache is used together with 
hibernate and holds also the standard query cache where the queries return resultsets
of size which may vary). My question is: what happens if JVM gets low on memory. My 
impression from reading the changelog of ehcache is that initially it was using soft
references, but since java 1.4 was cleaning them agressively, the soft references
were eventually dropped. Thus if the cache gets too big, I would just get
OutOfMemoryError? Nothing in Ehcache which tries to prevent it?

Answer (score 2):

You're correct in that if you want to create an OOM with ehcache you can do that. Have you had a look at the sizing options, though like maxEntriesLocalHeap / maxBytesLocalHeap. Using those you can effectively prevent caches to use more than an allocated amount of memory.

See for example http://ehcache.org/documentation/configuration/cache-size

Comment: thank you, I indeed had the impression that in recent versions of Ehcache one may explicitly limit the memory consumption. But my question was about Ehcache 1.2.3, since this is what is used in the system I am working on. And, again, currently my impression (not backed by an experiment) is that indeed, if the cache gets too big in terms of memory used (as opposed to number of elements used), Ehcache 1.2.3 will not try to evict entries to limit the memory consumption.